# React Native Web Browser Drawer not working

Tags: react-native, expo

I created a basic app using expo and react native and wanted to add a drawer navigation. I wanted the drawer to work on ios, android and web browser. So the mobile it works great and functions perfectly. However on the web browser when I open the application it starts the drawer in the open mode and then you can click anything that will make it close. It just stays open and wont close and there aren't really any errors.

Here is my code:

app.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import {
        ProfileScreen, 
        MessageScreen,
        ActivityScreen,
        ListScreen,
        ReportScreen,
        StatisticScreen,
        SignOutScreen  
      } from './src/screens';

import SideBar from './src/components/SideBar';

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    ProfileScreen,
    MessageScreen,
    ActivityScreen,
    ListScreen,
    ReportScreen,
    StatisticScreen,
    SignOutScreen
},
{
  drawerPosition: 'left',
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
//   contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
}
);

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
```

screen.js

```
export default class Screen extends React.Component {

    render () {
        return (
           <View style={styles.container}>
                <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{alignItems: "flex-end", margin: 16}}
                    onPress={this.props.navigation.openDrawer}
                    >
                     <FontAwesome5 name="bars" size={24} color="#161924" /> 
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={{flex:1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent:"center"}}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.name} Screen</Text>
                    </View>
                </SafeAreaView>
           </View>    
        );
    }

}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Screen from './Screen';

export const ProfileScreen = ({navigation}) => <Screen navigation={navigation} name="Profile" />;
export const MessageScreen = ({navigation}) => <Screen navigation={navigation} name="Message" />;
export const ActivityScreen = ({navigation}) => <Screen navigation={navigation} name="Activity" />;
export const ListScreen = ({navigation}) => <Screen navigation={navigation} name="List" />;
export const ReportScreen = ({navigation}) => <Screen navigation={navigation} name="Report" />;
export const StatisticScreen = ({navigation}) => <Screen navigation={navigation} name="Statistic" />;
export const SignOutScreen = ({navigation}) => <Screen navigation={navigation} name="SignOut" />;
```

sidebar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, ImageBackground, Image} from 'react-native';
import { DrawerNavigationItems } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import {Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons';

const Sidebar = props => {
    <ScrollView>
        <Text>Sidebar</Text>
    </ScrollView>
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default Sidebar;
```